# Change every control like TextBox's max length in big Asp.net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a situation where i have a very big project and i want to change max length property of every textbox that exist in application. How can i do this with small effort and without overhead on server.

Comment: Create a theme, in it write a textbox and set the max length and  give that theme to all pages.I am not sure if it would work but this would be the first thing i would try if i were you.

Comment: Do you just need to change the MaxLenght of the web control or do you (probably) also need to adjust the undelying layers (e.g business logic & data layer)?

Comment: @OkayGuy [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength.aspx) cannot be set by theme

Comment: @OkayGuy, themes are for changing UI related properties, not properties that affect the behavior of the control.

Comment: @JoãoAngelo [at]V4Vendetta well that is why i said try :D i wasn't sure, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a new class where you inherit from the standard TextBox.
2. Set/override the MaxLength property in the new class.
3. Use ASP.NET tag mapping to replace all instances of the standard TextBox with your new one. In web.config:

> ```
> <pages>
> . . .
>   <tagMapping>
>     <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"
>        mappedTagType="YouNamespace.YourTextBox" />
>   </tagMapping>
> </pages>
> ```

TagMapping is done by the compiler, so there's no added runtime overhead.

You could also use a control adapter, but in this case I think tag mapping may be cleaner and easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [control adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx) to customize the rendering of all the controls of a specified type, so this way you have control over the max length accepted by the text box.

From the [`ControlAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.adapters.controladapter.aspx) documentation (emphasis is mine):

> An adapter modifies a control for a specific browser or class of
>   browsers **or acts as an arbitrary filter on some capability**.

In this case the arbitrary filter would be a common `MaxLength` for all `TextBox` controls.

Answer (score 0):

Use search-replace option of text editors.

alternatively if you do not want to hard code it, use a common Java script file on page load. In this javascript set the MaxLenght of each TextBox of the page.

Something like this in Jquery should work for you

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     // replace 6 with new length you want to set
    $('input[type=text], textarea').attr('maxlength','6');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor. If all your TextBox controls on the project derives from System.Web.TextBox then make your own MyTextBox that derives from System.Web.TextBox and make all your textboxes derives from this instead.

So, in, the MyTextBox just set the preferred MaxLength